# Why can npm run babel-node from script but not as npm exec?

Tags: node.js, npm, lerna

In a lerna monorepo, babel is installed only at the root package level.
When running npm exec babel-node from `root/packages/packageA`, it fails with:

> npm ERR! could not determine executable to run

From the same directory, running `npm run test`, where test is just set to `babel-node` opens the babel-cli.

I.e. why can npm resolve the path to the root node_modules' bin when run as a script but cannot when run from the terminal directly?

EDIT:

I.e. https://github.com/bishonen/newproject/tree/master/packages/someapp

when running npm run test-babel, it will work from any of the 3 directories which contain a package.json.
When running npm exec babel-node, it will only work from the root directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Workspaces support for both npm run and npm exec would be supported in `npm@7.7.0` or greater. See the details [here](https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v7.7.0)

You can use the feature updating `npm`

```
npm i -g npm@7
```

I try it and it works in your code
https://github.com/bishonen/newproject/tree/master/packages/someapp

I use `npm` ***v7.12.0***

Comment: Thanks but that only works at root level, too. Added a github repo to clarify above